# Documentation on Documentation Beta

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is there a help section on the Documentation beta? The first topic I'm interested in is what kinds of content should be avoided or outright not allowed.

I can see the temptation for users, either or out of ignorance or because it's easy to do, to cut and paste text or examples from other sites into the Documentation section. I'm assuming that plagiarism is forbidden, but I didn't see any help topics or instructions on what we should be aiming for and what to avoid.

I think it would also be helpful to have a gold standard example, using either a real tag topic or a made up fictional one, so users had a reference and some standard to refer to.

Comment: There is a Documentation section on the help center coming, but the plagiarism case is covered in [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I can also see lots of high quality answers being turned into identical documentation posts.

Comment: There is a documentation topic within documentation that documents documenting ... good job this is meta... http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics

Comment: @Toby The link is broken... Page not found.

Comment: @LucM Actually it's not broken, but it's only available to certain users for the moment.

Comment: @LucM It's only available to users who had access to private-beta.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, with the public beta, there *is*, and you can see it even if you didn't participate in the private beta.

As the comments indicate, there are [docs of Docs in Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics). There's also some tips in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation). There have also been some [updates to existing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).